# How to simplify a jq sentence?

Tags: json, select, jq

I have this file test.json

```
  "items" : [ {
    "name" : "kudu-KUDU_TSERVER-2d63fec551a74320fdcc0c65007c76e4",
    "type" : "KUDU_TSERVER",
    "serviceRef" : {
      "clusterName" : "cluster",
      "serviceName" : "kudu"
    },
    "entityStatus" : "GOOD_HEALTH"
  }, {
    "name" : "kudu-KUDU_MASTER-95ebd4d9a5158d59306372ed306993fe",
    "type" : "KUDU_MASTER",
    "serviceRef" : {
      "clusterName" : "cluster",
      "serviceName" : "kudu"
    },
    "entityStatus" : "GOOD_HEALTH"
  }
... 
]
}
```

So I just want the value of *name*  when *type* is  KUDU_TSERVER

I am using this sentence

```
cat test |jq '.items[]' |jq  'select(.type == "KUDU_TSERVER" )' |jq -r '.name'
kudu-KUDU_TSERVER-2d63fec551a74320fdcc0c65007c76e4
kudu-KUDU_TSERVER-2f54da7e700b29f486dc977903077b42
kudu-KUDU_TSERVER-c6eed063790c0ebff3f4c3caa29f35c2
kudu-KUDU_TSERVER-668d476199e24b75dacdc2c142212d7f
kudu-KUDU_TSERVER-b19f608fc0b214334b7cb9aa8911f30d
kudu-KUDU_TSERVER-56aeb0bf37e61755e659be7ee1dd15cb
kudu-KUDU_TSERVER-4b773838c3f005671ea6ab1d77c69ff7
```

Are there a better way to do it?. I feel that this process it is not optimized

Comment: Hello Skiel, what's the optimization target? Large input file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely can do single jq query.

```
cat test | jq -r '.items[] | select(.type == "KUDU_TSERVER" ) | .name'
```

Other than that you could use `--stream` for large input files.